# Array in C Not Holding its value

Tags: arrays, c

Hello I am new here and new to C Programming. (I have several print statements to check the value at several stages).
***This is based off user input***
When I test with values, det[0] value keeps getting updated with the sol[2] value. Why is this???

When I print the det[0] value in the last line its value is 9 which is my sol[2] value. But in the previous code before it is (and should be) 2. Any solution that i type in sol[2] updates det[0] with the same value when my attempt is for it to maintain its value.

```
int main(void){
int det[8];
/*Equation 1*/
printf("Equation 1:\nx: ");
scanf("%d", &det[0]);
printf("y: ");
scanf("%d", &det[1]);
printf("z: ");
scanf("%d", &det[2]);
/*Equation 2 */
printf("Equation 2:\nx: ");
scanf("%d", &det[3]);
printf("y: ");
scanf("%d", &det[4]);
printf("z: ");
scanf("%d", &det[5]);
/*Equation 3 */
printf("Equation 3:\nx: ");
scanf("%d", &det[6]);
printf("y: ");
scanf("%d", &det[7]);
printf("z: ");
scanf("%d", &det[8]);
/*solve for determinant*/
int sol[2];
int maindet1 = det[0]*((det[4]*det[8])-(det[7]*det[5]))-det[1]*((det[3]*det[8])-(det[6]*det[5]))+det[2]*((det[3]*det[7])-(det[6]*det[4]));
printf("%d\n", maindet1);
printf("Solutions\nSolution1: ");
scanf("%d", &sol[0]);
printf("Solution2: ");
scanf("%d", &sol[1]);
printf("Solution3: ");
scanf("%d", &sol[2]);
printf("%d\n", maindet1);
printf("%d%d%d", sol[0],sol[1],sol[2]);
printf("%d\n", maindet1);
/*find determinant x*/
int detx = sol[0]*((det[4]*det[8])-(det[7]*det[5]))-det[1]*((sol[1]*det[8])-(sol[2]*det[5]))+det[2]*((sol[1]*det[7])-(sol[2]*det[4]));
printf("%d\n", detx);
int dety = det[0];
printf("%d\n", dety);
```

Comment: Because there is no `sol[2]` (and no `det[8]` either).

Comment: It's based off user input

Comment: It's not. `sol` has 2 elements. `det` has `8`. And they start with index `0`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, you have to specify *the number of elements*, not *the maximum index*, in declaration of arrays.

Your `det` have only 8 elements and your `sol` have only 2 elements, so reading nor writing to `det[8]` and/or `sol[2]` are not allowed.

Allocate enough elements like `int det[9];` and `int sol[3];` to resolve errors.

Comment: det[8] should take in 9 elements. Is that incorrect?

Comment: `det[8]` is 9th element, counting from `det[0]`. `int det[8];` has only 8 element and therefore it do not have an element `det[8]`.

Comment: When you declare det[8], det has 8 elements.  The first is det[0], the last is det[7].

Comment: In other words, it is using zero based indexing. [8] means 0-7. And [2] means 0-1.